# How can I see SSO (OpenID/OAuth) authorization token from the client side?

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, openid

I know how to view a SAML request/response from the HTTP requests in the browser, which I frequently do to troubleshoot SSO configurations (such as viewing the actual claims sent in the assertion)

Is there a way to see the JWT sent during SSO using OAuth/OIDC?

Asking this from the side of the IdP administrator, not as a developer/relying party administrator, and preferably without any browser extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the identity token is delivered in the backchannel using what is called an Authorization Code flow. There's no easy way to get it into the browser. However:

a) if you have access to the Client ID and Client Secret you may compose a POSTman call that exchanges the authorization code for an identity token by hand, see: [How can Postman get the OAuth 2.0 auth token in the authorization code flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198835/how-can-postman-get-the-oauth-2-0-auth-token-in-the-authorization-code-flow).

b) if you're able to change the so called "grant type" that the Client uses, you can use the Implicit grant type that will exchange tokens in the front channel thus accessible from a browser; you should note that this grant type is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

It's in the body of the response to the 'token' endpoint.